# Save a JTextField integer in an array by pressing a button

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have created this simple program and what i want it to do is that when i press a button the integer value that is in the `JTextField` is saved in an array, and I want to enter many values in that `JTextField` by pressing the button many times then add up all these values and outputs the sum. How do I do so?

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField teArdhurat_JTF = new JTextField(15);
    JButton teArdhurat_JB = new JButton("Fut");

    public Test() {
        setTitle("BILANCI");
        setSize(370, 270);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel teArdhurat_JP = new JPanel();
        teArdhurat_JP.add(teArdhurat_JTF);
        teArdhurat_JP.add(teArdhurat_JB);

        c.add(teArdhurat_JP);
        teArdhurat_JB.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String teArdhurat_GT = teArdhurat_JTF.getText();
        int teArdhurat = Integer.parseInt(teArdhurat_GT);

        ArrayList<Integer> te_ardhurat = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList());

        //Here is the problem the next value that I enter overwrites the previous value

        if (e.getSource() == teArdhurat_JB) {
            te_ardhurat.add(teArdhurat);
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < te_ardhurat.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + te_ardhurat.get(i);
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want sum of digits entered in the textbox ?

Comment: I want to fill the ArrayList<Integer> te_ardhurat = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList()); by entering a value in JText field a pressing the button i have created

Answer (score 0):

Because everytime you are calling actionPerformed method it is creating a new ArrayList with no data.The scope of this ArrayList is till the end of the method and will be stored in stack.

You will need a class member variable in your case.

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField teArdhurat_JTF = new JTextField(15);
    JButton teArdhurat_JB = new JButton("Fut");
    private final ArrayList<Integer> te_ardhurat = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the way you layout the components is not good. Hence I thought of writing a solution from the scratch. Please go through this and learn more about how to layout swing components in a panel more professional way.

```
package com.java.demo;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    private TestFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super();

        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] { 100, 0 };
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(textField, gbc);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel totalLabel = new JLabel("Total:");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 1, 1, 5);
        contentPane.add(totalLabel, gbc);

        JButton sumButton = new JButton("Sum");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 8);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(sumButton, gbc);
        sumButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                totalLabel.setText("Total: " + numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());

            }
        });

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.